# How do I convert a SQL Server Convert(float,substring([table].[field],x,y) to an Access SQL

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I have converted all of my SQL Server commands to ACCESS except one.  Here is the code in SQL Server Syntax that I cannot figure out which commands to use.  The Code takes an hour value stored as a string of three or four characters, e.g., 25:00, 2:30, 09:20, etc. and converts them to a number equivalent, e.g., 25, 2.5, 9.33333, etc.  Can someone provide me with the correct commands to use in place of convert, float, and substring?  Here is my Code:

```
(
  (
    iif(LEN(dbo_t_MakerProcesses.ProcessTarget) = 5 
        AND 
        SUBSTRING(dbo_t_MakerProcesses.ProcessTarget,3,1) = ':',
          convert(float, substring(dbo_t_MakerProcesses.ProcessTarget, 1, 2) 
            + '.' 
            +substring(dbo_t_MakerProcesses.ProcessTarget, 4, 2)),0
       )
       -Round(iif(LEN(dbo_t_MakerProcesses.ProcessTarget) = 5 
                  AND  SUBSTRING(dbo_t_MakerProcesses.ProcessTarget,3,1) = ':',
                  convert(float,substring(dbo_t_MakerProcesses.ProcessTarget, 1, 2)
                                + '.'+substring(dbo_t_MakerProcesses.ProcessTarget,4,2)),
                 0),0,1
             )
  )/.6
)+
Round(
      iif(
          LEN(dbo_t_MakerProcesses.ProcessTarget) = 5 
          AND 
          SUBSTRING(dbo_t_MakerProcesses.ProcessTarget,3,1) = ':',
           convert(float,substring(dbo_t_MakerProcesses.ProcessTarget, 1, 2) 
                         + '.'
                         +substring(dbo_t_MakerProcesses.ProcessTarget, 4, 2)
                  ),0
          ),0,1
      ) AS Target
```

Comment: Please always try to format your code, it's hard to read code like that, I just try to make it a bit more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Convert are as follows (you may need to look up more):

```
 Cdbl()
 CInt()
 CStr()
 CLng()
```

Float :

```
 Double
```

And SubString:

```
 MID( text, start_position, [number_of_characters] )
```

Comment: Also worht noting you can use a pass thru query and not need to convert your query to Access SQL. Access SQL has its limitations

Comment: Doug, thank you.  I figured out the substring, but will work with the convert and float today. I found the pass thru query instructions after doing all of the work to convert the code.  I am going to create another version of the database and play with the pass thru.